# Neo4J: Return one random node for every match in list of arguments

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create a single Cypher query that will return a list of nodes, where each item in the list is a random node from a MATCH query.

For example, I have a list of (Genes) that "reside" at a (Locus).
I want to get one random Gene node for every locus position [0, 1, 2, 3...] and return it as a list.

I've been trying to use this query but it only returns one Gene result, rather than a list of Genes:

`WITH [0,1,2] AS locus
UNWIND locus as lp
MATCH (g:Gene)-[:resides]-(:Locus{position:lp, chromosome_pair: 0}) 
WITH lp, g, rand() as r ORDER BY r LIMIT 1
WITH COLLECT(g) as gw, lp
return lp, gw`

I am having problems collecting the result of each loop in the UNWIND (second last line), it is only returning one result rather than 3 (as I asked for locus position 0, 1 and 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the limit cuts off the entire stream, use the collection:

```
WITH [0,1,2] AS locus
UNWIND locus AS lp
MATCH (g:Gene)-[:resides]-(:Locus{position:lp, chromosome_pair: 0}) 
WITH lp, 
     g ORDER BY rand()
WITH lp, 
     collect(g)[0..1] AS g // take the first item in the collection
WITH collect(g) AS gw,
     lp
RETURN lp, 
       gw
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly! I was trying to do this for hours to no avail.